# For two or more arrays of objects how can you remove first elements until all first elements match on a field

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

I have a typescript Map object defined like

```
const stat_map: Map<string, IMonthlyStat[]> = new Map();
```

Lets say IMonthlyStat is defined like below (In reality there are more fields)

```
export interface IMonthlyStat {
  month: string;
  value: number;
}
```

The trouble is the values of the Map ie the IMonthlyStat[] arrays can have different month fields as data was added in the db at different times.

The month field is a string defined like 2021-02-01T00:00:00.000 UTC.

What would be the best way to remove the initial elements of some of the IMonthlyStat arrays so
they all end up with the same starting month string ?

For example if we had two IMonthlyStat arrays like

```
[
    {month: '2021-02-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 6}, 
    {month: '2021-03-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 8}, 
    {month: '2021-04-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 10}
]
```

and

```
[
    {month: '2021-03-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 7}, 
    {month: '2021-04-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 9}
]
```

how can I end up with

```
[
    {month: '2021-03-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 8}, 
    {month: '2021-04-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 10}
]
```

and

```
[
     {month: '2021-03-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 7}, 
     {month: '2021-04-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 9}
]
```

Comment: Are months always unique inside each array? Are arrays always sorted by month in ascending order? Do they always end with the same month? Is it possible two arrays do not have a common starting month?

Comment: Let's say you have 3 arrays, and that you can achieve it by removing 2 entries from array 1, one entry from array 2, and none from array3. Let's say you can also achieve it in other ways, like removing 3 entries from array 3. And there could be other ways as well... What should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, here's a function that transforms an array of arrays so that all arrays start with the same element, provided there's at least one element common to all arrays. The equality of elements is determined by the key function: `key(A) == key(B) -> A equals B`

```js
function alignBy(arrays, keyFn) {
    for (let x of arrays[0]) {
        let indexes = arrays.map(a => 
            a.findIndex(y => keyFn(x) === keyFn(y)))
        if (indexes.every(i => i >= 0))
            return arrays.map((a, n) => a.slice(indexes[n]))
    }
}

//

a = [
    {month: '1', value: 6},
    {month: '2', value: 8},
    {month: '3', value: 10},
    {month: '5', value: 9},
]

b = [
    {month: '2', value: 7},
    {month: '3', value: 9},
    {month: '4', value: 9},
    {month: '6', value: 9},
]

c = [
    {month: '3', value: 7},
    {month: '3', value: 9},
    {month: '4', value: 9},
    {month: '5', value: 9},
]


res = alignBy([a, b, c], x => x.month)
for (a of res) {console.log(...a); console.log('----')}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Approach 1 with array.filter() and array.some()

If I understood your requirement correctly, you basically need to return the elements of the two arrays where there is an intersection on the dates.

You can do this using array.filter() and array.some().

- Array.filter() will return only the elements of the array which match a specific condition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter.
- Array.some() checks that a specific condition within the array matches, and returns the first match: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some.

The two functions can be combined. The code below will return an array containing the items in array1 where the .month value is also contained in an item in array2. For your use case you can just repeat it to get items from array1 and then array2.

The main thing which I think is different to your original request is that it doesn't only search for the first matching element, it checks the whole array so depending on the size of the array it could end up in too much processing.

```
let intersection = array1.filter(x => array2.some(y=> x.month === y.month));
```

Try this runnable snippet for a simple implementation of it:

```js
let array1 = [
    {month: '2021-02-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 6}, 
    {month: '2021-03-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 8}, 
    {month: '2021-04-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 10}
];

let array2 = [
    {month: '2021-03-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 7}, 
    {month: '2021-04-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 9}
];

let intersection = array1.filter(x => array2.some(y=> x.month === y.month));
let intersection2 = array2.filter(x => array1.some(y=> x.month === y.month));

console.log(intersection);
console.log(intersection2);
```

## Approach 2 with findIndex()

Assuming your arrays are always sorted by month and you really only care about matching the first element, you can do this:

1. Compare the first items of the two arrays to find the latest month
2. Find the index of that month in each of the arrays with `findIndex()`
3. Splice the arrays based on that index

Here's a simple implementation of that in a runnable snippet. There is a bit more code that the first approach but as it only checks the first item in the array and then splices it should be much more efficient, taking into account the limitations I mentioned in my assumptions.

```js
let array1 = [
    {month: '2021-02-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 6}, 
    {month: '2021-03-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 8}, 
    {month: '2021-04-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 10}
];

let array2 = [
    {month: '2021-03-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 7}, 
    {month: '2021-04-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 9}
];

processedArray1 = [];
processedArray2 = [];

// find the latest first month from each of the arrays
const latestFirstMonth = array1[0].month >= array2[0].month ? array1[0].month : array2[0].month;

// find index of that latest month for each array (will be 0 for the array with the latest month at the start)
const array1Index = array1.findIndex(element => element.month >= latestFirstMonth);
const array2Index = array2.findIndex(element => element.month >= latestFirstMonth);

// splice the arrays based on that index
processedArray1 = array1.splice(array1Index);
processedArray2 = array2.splice(array2Index);

console.log(processedArray1);
console.log(processedArray2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const IMonthlyStat1= [
    {month: '2021-02-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 6}, 
    {month: '2021-03-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 8}, 
    {month: '2021-04-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 10}
]
 
const IMonthlyStat2= [
    {month: '2021-03-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 7}, 
    {month: '2021-04-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 9}
]

function compareArrayDates(array1, array2){

if (array1 === array2){
    return {
        result1: array1,
        result2: array2
    }
}
 
const initialDayArray1Elements = array1[0].month.split('T')[0].split('-')
const initialDayArray2Elements = array2[0].month.split('T')[0].split('-')

const utcDate1 = new Date(initialDayArray1Elements[0], initialDayArray1Elements[1], initialDayArray1Elements[2]);
const utcDate2 = new Date(initialDayArray2Elements[0], initialDayArray2Elements[1], initialDayArray2Elements[2]);

const dateDifference = utcDate1 < utcDate2 // If true we need to remove Dates in array1 else we need to remove Dates in array2
//console.log(dateDifference)
if(dateDifference){
    return removeDates(array1, array2)
} else {
    return removeDates(array2, array1)
}
}


function removeDates(mutableArray, inmutableArray){
    const initialDayInmutableArrayMonth = inmutableArray[0].month

    while(mutableArray[0].month !== initialDayInmutableArrayMonth){
        mutableArray.shift()
    }

    return {
        result1: mutableArray,
        result2: inmutableArray
    }    
}

const { result1, result2 } = compareArrayDates(IMonthlyStat1, IMonthlyStat2)

console.log(result1)

console.log(result2)

/*
[
  { month: '2021-03-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 8 },
  { month: '2021-04-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 10 }
]
[
  { month: '2021-03-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 7 },
  { month: '2021-04-01T00:00:00.000 UTC', value: 9 }
]
*/
```